# Storm Door installation issue

Tags: doors

I bought an Anderson Storm door that should fit a 36"x80" opening. However, the width of my opening is 35 1/4" which is less than the required 35 7/8".  The height seems to be ok.  What should I do?  Take a router to one side of the jamb and cut it down about 1/2" so it fits into the opening?

Comment: Post some photos or a sketch or something. There's not much to work with here. Also link to the exact storm door. Most mount to the surface of the existing door frame and don't really have the constraint you describe.

Comment: You might be measuring the brickmold on the door. I had a similar issue, however, when I installed mine I had to move it out to avoid the handles hitting. I pulled the brickmold off the door, installed the new wider brickmold and then installed the door.

Comment: Here's a link to the door: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Andersen-36-in-x-80-in-3000-Series-White-Right-Hand-Self-Storing-Easy-Install-Aluminum-Storm-Door-with-Nickel-Hardware-3SNEZR36WH/203145053

Comment: I removed the brick mold from the door frame before trying the install.  While the storm door does mount to the face of the door frame, the storm door frame is suppose to sit inside of the existing jambs to a depth of about 1" recessed into the opening.  It doesn't fit.